# Multi-domain certificate for postfix

Tags: postfix, email-server, debian-squeeze, iredmail

I'm trying to get full green marks on an old iredmail server [checktls.com/TestReceiver](https://www.checktls.com/TestReceiver).
I have a multi-domain certificate with these domains:

- mail.domain.tld
- mailgw.domain.tld
- mailgw2.domain.tld

I do get the full green marks on mail.domain.tld, but not the others. I'm assuming this is because of mail.domain.tld being the certificate name (I've forgotten what it's called).

The warning I get on the other domains is this:

```
Cert Hostname DOES NOT VERIFY (mailgw.domain.tld != mail.domain.tld | DNS:mail.domain.tld)
        So email is encrypted but the host is not verified
```

MX and A records are set for each domain. They don't share a single IP, but rather each have their own.

What do I need to do change to solve this issue?
Do I need to make separate certificates for each domain?

Version information:

- Postfix 2.7.1
- Dovecot 1.2.15
- iRedMail 0.8.5
- Debian 6.0.10 (Squeeze)

I know these are old versions and I know one should upgrade (or rather migrate), but that's currently not possible for me to do.

I will supply any information needed (unless told not to by my boss).

Comment: Are you sure your certificate is actually multi-domain? Checktls should list all the `DNS:` entries from the certificate SAN extension, but it prints only one in your case.

Comment: @Lacek I'm pretty sure it is, but I'll double check tomorrow.

Comment: @Lacek You were right. acme.sh had done something with the certificate *configuration* file, but nothing with the certificate itself. Thanks for leading me in the right direction.